# Status field is not update through Community User

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, community, salesforce1-app, service-console

I have to update the status field through "Community User" but it is showing this error.[image]

I have created the quick action for change the status and drop on it on the community ,through my "Community Plus" members case status is changing but not through "Community User"

Answer (score 0):

> The Customer Community Plus license is similar to the legacy Customer Portal: Enterprise Administration license.

So, Community plus license user will be able to update `Case` even if its not shared with him (because they can act as delegated administrator).

On other hand, community license user needs the case to be shared with them to be able to update `Case`. Check if user has edit access to Case using below query in anonymous window:

```
System.debug([SELECT RecordId, HasEditAccess 
          FROM UserRecordAccess 
          WHERE UserId = '--user_id--' 
          AND RecordId = '--case_id--']);
```